# How to make a bootable usb which runs Lubuntu off RAM, and has persistance?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

**Check my Answer below.**
**I am still having some issues, a user is reporting that their pendrive gets too hot while using.**

I have a laptop with no HDD. I am hoping to make a bootable USB with Lubuntu that runs off RAM, and has persistance.

Here are my requirements:-

1. The pendrive the owner of the laptop (A CS student, my underclassmen) gave me is 16G kingston.
2. The lubuntu **should run off RAM**, totally. Like Puppy linux! However, it should be possible that some applications like Office or Firefox are only loaded into ram as needed. What I want is to maximize the life of the pendrive while keeping the system fast.
3. The lubuntu **should be under 1GB of RAM** while running, the laptop has 4GB ram. To be clear, I mean when the OS is running with firefox, word, etc. it should still be under 3.2GB at most, this laptop slows down if 3.6GB that mark is reached surely due to switching between SWAP stored on a slow HDD.
4. Here is a list of applications it needs:

   1. Vim
   2. Word-editor(any)
   3. Spreadsheet-editor(any)
   4. APT(if possible)
   5. Firefox/Chrome
   6. VLC
   7. NodeJS, Python, GCC, Ruby, Perl, etc.
   8. PDF reader(any)
   9. Pandoc, PDFlatex, etc.
   10. Curl, htop, a network-manager, AWK, etc. All standard linux tools. The student intends to learn heavy use of the CLI.
5. **Must not have swap**, for longer life of the pendrive. This is just a suggestion I took from another post. I could use some more info on this. The pendrive gets hot if It try to transfer a 10GB file on it at 8/MBPS.
6. It must have persistant storage, anything downloaded in /Home or its sub-directories, and anything installed via APT should be permenent. OS and desktop setting too.
7. Must have 8GB+ space leftover for Files.

Here are my relevant skills:-

1. I can use cfdisk.
2. Have installed Arch in text-mode over 400+ times for myself and others.
3. I use Debian and Ubuntu based distros, Sometimes Arch, I don't use or own a windows.
4. I am fluent is a lot of programming languages including C/C++, SH, etc.
5. I can use Rufus, Ventoy, Etcher, Unetbootin, etc. I use rufus via a VM, so avoiding it is a good thing for me.

**How should I move about this project?** I was thinking the following:

1. Create 2 partitions on the Pen drive, say <4GB and >12GB. Maybe even a 200MB boot partition.
2. Creating an ISO from VM and the default Lubuntu ISO. Remove and Add software as needed, and set it to mount the >12GB partition upon booting, then save the ISO. Which tool should I use btw? Cubic?
3. Use Unetbootin to put it on the pendrive.
4. Boot from the pendrive, then the OS will be loaded onto the RAM. The pendrive will remain inside for persistance.

Edit: It dosen't need to be Lubuntu, as long as it similar to Ubuntu, as in it uses APT, LXDE, etc. All it needs are stuff like AbiWord, NodejS, Vim, etc. Nothing too flashy, I picked lubuntu for its support.

Edit: The Ram on the Laptop is 4GB, so atleast 2GB needs to be free for other applications. I mean firefox alone takes 1GB+ if used conservatively. My problem with puppy linux is that it is not using APT as its primary package manager and I am not very fimilar with puppy either. Is there really no way to strip-down lubuntu to only APT, Coreutils, Vim, AbiWord, etc. and get it under 1GB footprint?

Edit: I have never used **mkusb**, only have used **dd** once.

Edit: I apologise to cause confusion. The thing is that I use a seperate Dell ATOM laptop with Arch, it runs in text-mode only, with optional i3. I have used it for all my programming needs all through the undergrad semesters, and I still use it for everything. I have only needed to run a desktop-environment for stuff like Cisco-networking tools, CAD, etc. On that system the applications I use the most are vim, gcc, NodeJS, w3m, curl, sh, python, pandoc, pdflatex, etc. Also regular linux tools like AWK, HTOP, LESS, Less-pipes, etc. not counting the package manager. I also used abiword, but now use libre-Word and Libre-Excel. I want this HP machiene to have a distro that is exactly like the ATOM one, but with APT and possibly Ubuntus LTS since the owner of this HP has no experience with Arch, only Ubuntu. The primary requirements are for it to be light weight, not over-flowing the RAM in any case, and it should run off RAM entirely.

Edit: To guiverc: I get your point. I will pick a better application package. Do you have any suggestions? My preference is something with Libre-Word and Libre-SpreadSheet, etc. You got me thinking that the user might be better off on Chrome because they use ElectronJS a lot.

Edit: To user68186: the only requirement I have is to **not overflow the RAM**. Avoiding swap if possible! I was thinking that as the OS boots the RAM used is under 1GB, I have disfigured and riced several Ububtu distros to work under 300MB, and as the user ran theirs applications the rams goes up to 1.5GB max, never over as long as they don't overdo firefox. I want to do the same thing here.

Comment: You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and get most of what you want, if you use dus-persistent. Please be aware that the persistent storage is not in RAM, but the image of the software from the iso file will be there.

Comment: The current versions of Lubuntu are too big to fit within 1 GB of RAM, so it will be impossible. You must either accept to use more RAM or use another (non-Ubuntu) Linux distro, for example Puppy Linux, that you mentioned in the original question. Or forget about RAM. Then Lubuntu and even [this Kinetic Ubuntu server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-preinstalled/pending/kinetic-preinstalled-server-amd64.img.xz) system are OK, if you add an ultra-light desktop environment or a simple window manager. See also [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: *"It needs to have AbiWord, Excel(any), APT, Firefox, VLC, NodeJS, Python, GCC, Zathura PDF reader, etc."* If you need to install apps it may be worthwhile to a **full install** of a Linux distro in the USB, rather than a **persistent USB".

Comment: I use a laptop with 4GB RAM with Ubuntu 20.04 with all the default apps like LibreOffice and Firefox. This is not a problem. **Under 1 GB of RAM** is a bogus requirement.

Comment: FYI:  I used `asus eepc 1000HE (intel atom n270, 1gb, intel mobile 945gse integrated), wireless RT2790` in QA-testing release of Lubuntu up to 19.04 (*disco*), however as it was *i386* only, no *supported* release of Lubuntu will run on it; so it was the equivalent of a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server install with LXDE today (for 18.04, LXQt for 18.10/19.04)... I only used it with installed OSes, not *live* with persistence & I always preferred the speed/ease of swap (*over no-swap*). Lubuntu of any *supported* release isn't LXDE so won't help you.

Comment: "Edit: I have never used mkusb, only have used dd once": Then it is time to try it ;-) Please be aware that is is made for Ubuntu & family flavours and may or may not work in Arch (the current version of mkusb is not tested in Arch). Clone a Lubuntu iso file to your own USB pendrive, boot into it and you can install and run mkusb in your own USB live Lubuntu drive and create a persistent live Lubuntu in your student's USB pendrive.

Comment: I downloaded `archlinux-2022.05.01-x86_64.iso`, cloned it to a USB pendrive, booted it and installed `dus-plus` (with `dus` which is part of mkusb) from [github.com/sudodus/tarballs](https://github.com/sudodus/tarballs). It works in text mode after installation from its tarball, and I could create persistent live Lubuntu 22.04 LTS in another USB drive. So now the `dus` part of mkusb is verified in a current Arch live system. It should also work in an installed Arch with/without a graphic desktop environment. (If you install `dialog` you get a nice TUI for `dus`, but it is not necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

Since there were no answers to this question I decided to post my own solution to this problem, mostly because the future me is going to need it.

With this method I have created 4 pendrives with Lubuntu. All of them ran properly off laptops with less than 1GB of RAM and no Storage-Drives. All of them had Applications like AbiWord, Gnumeric, Firefox, Vim, GCC, NodeJS, ElectronJS, etc. The four people (including) me used them for a day and had no problems at all!

**Note:** When I say 'larger partition of the pendrive' I mean the partition used to store the ISO files, not the optional extra partition used to store regular pendrive stuff. The ISO partition will usually be named "/dev/sdb1", but that is not always the case.

## Steps

I have Installed a Lubuntu on the Pendrive using Ventoy with persistence, then I put the usb on the desired laptop and installed all the required drivers, libraries, packages, etc. Following is a summary of the steps I took for this:-

1. Download the **ventoy-1.0.74-linux.tar.gz** package. Extract it to a directory, and open a terminal in that directory. It will have the following useful scripts:

   - `./VentoyGUI.x86_64` for x86_64 GUI, and similar GUI scripts for other system architectures.
   - `./CreatePersistentImg.sh` for creating a virtual hdd as a `.dat` file.
   - `./ExtendPersistentImg.sh` for increasing the size of a virtual hdd.
   - `./VentoyPlugson` for managing plugins.
2. Run one of the GUI scripts, I used `sudo ./VentouGUI.x86_64`.
3. In the GUI find options for MBR, secure-boot, and extra-space at the end of the drive. **I enablen MBR and secure-boot**, but since the pendrive I had was only 16GB I didn't use the extra-space option. More on this later!
4. Using the user friendly GUI **install Ventoy** on the Pendrive of your choice. Make sure the Pendrive is pluged in. Also *make sure that you have picked the Pendrive* of your choice, and *not your own hard-drive* from the GUI's dropdown menu.
5. You can use `lsblk` to check out the Pendrive. It will have 2 partitions, one will be around 32MB, and the other will be the size of the rest of the Pendrive if you have not used the extra-space option. Mine was 15GB.
6. Create a Virtual Hard-drive using the `sudo sh ./CreatePersistentImg.sh`. After this script ends processing you will see a file named `persistence.dat` or something similar, it will be 1GB in size. This file will act as the HDD of your OS installed on the Pendrive.
7. Move the `persistence.dat` file in the Pendrive, in the larger partition of the pendrive.
8. Move your OS-ISO to the larger partition of the pendrive too.
9. Use the `sudo sh ./ExtendPersistentImg.sh ADDRESS_TO_YOUR_PERSISTENCE.DAT_FILE_IN_USB SPACE_TO_EXTEND_IN_MBs` to extend the size of the `.dat` file. Mine looked like `sudo sh ./ExtendPersistentImg.sh /media/raytherepairman/Ventoy/persistence.dat 9000`.
10. Use `sudo sh VentoyPlugson.sh /dev/sdb` to boot the plugin-manager server. It will give you a URL, visit it in a web-browser to check out the Web-GUI.
11. In the Plugson web-gui go to the Persistence tab, there add a new persistence entry, it will ask you for the address of the ISO file and the persistence.dat file on the Pendrive, both as absolute paths. Then submit your paths. Also set `autosel` to 1.
12. The web-gui will show the status of the connection, if its ok you will see a 'ventoy' directory in the larger partition of the pendrive,  with a `.json` file inside.

If you did it properly then your pendriveOS is ready, and you can put it in laptop to boot from it. The files you save will be stored safely through reboots and shutdowns.

I have also created a drive with extra 32GB space using the extra-spact-at-end option of the Ventoy-GUI, formatted it using cfdisk. The user is able to use his Pendrive both as a bootable and a Pendrive.

In 2 of the drives I have created the OS was booting off a installation ISO downloaded from the official website, hence many of the issues like booting to a language selection prompt, then selecting the "Try Lubuntu without installing" option was becoming tiresome. So in the 3rd and 4th pendrive I use VirtualBox to install Lubuntu from the installation ISO into an empty ISO file. Then the "issues" were gone.

I am very open to suggestions to improve this process!